# Does facebook dialog of android sdk allows setting the feed text?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

i've tried to set text(which will be written in feed) using `ShareDialogBuilder` and `FeedDialogBuilder`.
but, it seems there is no any to set plain text in dialogs. they just allows setting the data of link section
I want to show default text with facebook dialogs.
Is there any way to implement that? how?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible, this is Facebook policy only the user should write text in his posts.

More information at:[Facebook policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22123047/2065418)