# How to share predefined text on Facebook via ShareDialog Android

Tags: android, facebook

i have a big problem for sharing text via ShareDialog. It seems i can only share predefined links,descriptions... but not text. Is there any other way to share text of Facebook from my Android app.
My code is:

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForLink().build();

 private FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilderForLink() {
    return new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)

            .setCaption("Here Comes the Boom!!!!")
            .setName("Hello Facebook")
            .setDescription("Here is my description")
            .setLink("http://developers.facebook.com/android");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible, you have to use the Facebook api to do this.

More informations here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22123047/2065418

Comment: Hmm thank you, but it must be some other way to do this.

Comment: Not without the facebook api !

Comment: Ok, i understand i see a backdoor maybe i can put the text on description.

Comment: If it is impossible then why does the builder even have methods setName(...) setDescription(..) .. etc? This doesnt make sense

Comment: Well i guess it was possible a long time ago, and then they restricted the possibilities. It's very annoying, but their is not other solutions than use their API !

Comment: The official FB docs says under share dialog "You can also use this method to post a status update on the user's behalf...."  Please see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

Comment: Ok, so if you read further it also says "To post a status update, make the link parameter null and the dialog will appear empty for the user to write their status update in it....". They seem to contradict their earlier statement.....!

Comment: Just to clarify one point, the methods setName() and setDescription() are used, but if the webpage the link points to has it's own details defined it'll use those instead (seems wrong to me). If you use an invalid link, you will see the details you set appear correctly in the Facebook post. The user can still add their own status update.

Answer (score 1):

Code for **Facebook** sharing text/link

```
public void post(String post_text) {

    Bundle postParam = new Bundle();

    Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {

            // shareDialog.dismiss();
            // showPublishResult("Photo Post", response.getGraphObject(),
            // response.getError());
        }
    };
    Session session = createSession();
    postParam.putString("name", post_text);

    postParam.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");

    Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParam,
            HttpMethod.POST, callback);

    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();

}
```