# Facebook share with default status post

Tags: ios, objective-c, fbsdksharekit

In one of our app, we are supposed to give an option to share newly unlocked Achievement. Requirement also includes to post defined text if share box is empty.

The problem is, we are unable to find relevant delegate method when user clicks on POST/Send button.

Code for posting status is,

```
    FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:awardToBeShareOnFB];
    content.contentTitle = @"Helloworld";
    content.contentDescription = @"Helloworld";

    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:[self parentViewController]
                                 withContent:content
                                    delegate:self];
```

It should post "Helloworld" as a status if posting box is empty.

[image]

Comment: FBSDK is open source. Debug it to find the method you are looking for.

Comment: You can't predefine the text now since a year ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Share via Intent Text not Shown in Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235272/android-share-via-intent-text-not-shown-in-facebook)

Comment: Doc link of Platform Policy 2.3: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill